# How to test RN component rendering inside modal & portal in react native

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, react-native-paper, native-testing-library

I am using [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/) library as my UI component library.I am using Modal component which gets rendered inside Portal, something like below

```
<Portal>
   <Modal visible={visible}>
    ....
   </Modal>
</Portal>
```

For writing unit test cases I am using [@testing-library/react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-native).

My question is how can I testing components rendering inside model. When I am using **debug()** not getting Modal node in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are "not getting Modal node in it", but one thing you can do, if you aren't testing the `Portal` component, is just mock it with a `View` component and just test what is inside `Modal`.

```
jest.mock('react-native-paper', () => {
  const RealModule = jest.requireActual('react-native-paper');
  const MockedModule = {
    ...RealModule,
    Portal: ({children}) => <View>{children}</View>
  };
  return MockedModule;
});
```

There's other ways of mocking the component, if you have some problems, please take a look at [this doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#mock-native-modules-using-jestmock)

Comment: Thanks @Vencovsky, it worked. Marking answer as accepted.